# Passing array in FormBody

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-core, parameter-passing, postman

Action

```
[HttpPost("TestArray")]
public IActionResult TestArray([FromBody] int[]a )
{
    return Ok( a);
}
```

Output in postman

```
{
    "": [
        "The input was not valid."
    ]
}
```

[image: postman request]

I tried to send it as `[FromQuery]` it's pass
but when I use Name property for `FromQuery`
as `[FromQuery (Name ="a")]`,
but frombody don't have any property
and *when i didn't send any thing return same error* what i should to do to if want an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to send body as JSON

[image]

Comment: okay thanks but  what i should to do if i have multiple parameter like
int []a  , string Name 
and so thanks

Comment: if you want to pass more data. The best option is creating a model for it. For example, { values: [1,2,3], name: "my name", address: "add 123" }